# Use D3.min to find lowest value that is not 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use D3 to find the lowest value in my dataset. However, I also have values that are 0, but I want D3 to find the lowest value that is not 0.

Currently I am using:

```
d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.houseValues; })
```

But obviously this returns 0 sometimes, when a 0 is found.

Is there a way to do this? Or is the only solution to build a normal for-loop with an if-statement to ignore the 0 values..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the constant `Infinity`, since `Math.min(Infinity, someNumber)` always return `someNumber` (unless `someNumber` is also infinity). So it'll look like this:

```
smallest = d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.houseValues || Infinity; })
```

If needed, you can check `smallest == Infinity`, which would be `true` in the case that all house values were 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering the data to remove zeroes first, e.g.

```
var noZeroes = data.filter(function(d) { return d.houseValues !== 0; });
d3.min(noZeroes, function(d) {return d.houseValues; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @meetamit's answer, if you want `smallest` to be `undefined` when the data has all zeros, use `undefined` instead of `Infinity`.

[`d3.min()` "ignores undefined, null and NaN values"](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#min).

```js
const data1 = [
  {
    houseValues: 0,
  },
  {
    houseValues: 100000,
  },
  {
    houseValues: 150000,
  },
];

const data2 = [
  {
    houseValues: 0,
  },
  {
    houseValues: 0,
  },
];

smallest = d3.min(data1, function(d) { return d.houseValues; });

smallestNonZero = d3.min(data1, function(d) { return d.houseValues || undefined });

smallestAllZeros = d3.min(data2, function(d) { return d.houseValues || undefined });


console.log(smallest);
console.log(smallestNonZero);
console.log(smallestAllZeros);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```